# php, return a specific object value from json and assign it to variable

Tags: php, json

How can I assign client_id to a variable in my php script?

```
{
      "success": true,
      "client_id": "14",
      "call": "addClient",
      "server_time": 1323785423,
      "info": [
         "New client account created"
      ]
   }
```

How can I assign client_id to a variable in my php script?

the following is the command i used to generate the above json output.

```
  $return = HBWrapper::singleton()->addClient($params);
```

and I used return in a foreach loop.

```
  foreach ($return as $id) { 
    echo $id->client_id;
}
```

Comment: Json is a string, so you'll need to convert it into either and object or array using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you're trying to directly access the string without converting it, referencing it as an object can be achieved with `json_decode($string)`

```
$return = json_decode(HBWrapper::singleton()->addClient($params));

foreach ($return as $id) { 
    echo $id->client_id;
}
```